# on $_GET set $_SESSION wont work

Tags: php, session, get

I need to get the last non-empty value that `$_GET['id_item']` had

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['id_item']) || $_SESSION['id_item']===''  || ( isset($_GET['id_item']) && !$_GET['id_item'] === '' )){
    $_SESSION['id_item'] = $_GET['id_item'];
}else{
   /*no need to update*/
}

echo $_SESSION['id_item']   /*   Allways in blank    :S   */
```

And `var_dump($_GET)` outputs:

```
array(1) { ["id_item"]=> string(2) "50" }
```

Any idea why the `$_SESSION` is not saved?

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: You also forgot the ; on the last line of the code you provided.

Comment: can you echo $_GET['id_item']? see if its empty or not

Comment: @RobinVanPersithe var_dump shows its not empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix this:

`$_SESSION['id_item']==''` to `$_SESSION['id_item']===''`

or you can use:

```
empty($_SESSION['id_item'])
```

Comment: i edited the question a little bit. you answer worked for the first get value, but in the next one, s_session stays empty

Answer (score 1):

unless you expect a (valid) ID to be `0` you can reduce `!isset($_SESSION['id_item']) || $_SESSION['id_item']===''` to `empty($_SESSION['id_item'])`. `!$_GET['id_item'] === ''` is always false, as this translates to `false === ''`. You were probably looking for `$_GET['id_item'] !== ''`. Again, if `0` is not a valid value, you can go for `!empty($_GET['id_item'])` here.

That said, the whole `!isset($_SESSION['id_item']) || $_SESSION['id_item']===''` part of the condition doesn't make much sense. The second part "if _GET id_item present" is always necessary for the condition's body (`$_SESSION['id_item'] = $_GET['id_item'];`) to work. So you can reduce your condition to

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['id_item'])) {
    // import new id_item
    $_SESSION['id_item'] = $_GET['id_item'];
} elseif (!isset($_SESSION['id_item'])) {
    // make sure we don't run into an undefined array index notice
    $_SESSION['id_item'] = null;
}

var_dump($_SESSION['id_item]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you output anything before the `start_session`. If so it will be unable to send the cookie. This is probably why it is not working.

Comment: it's not a cookie, its a session var!

Comment: The server sends a cookie to the browser so that future pages it knows what session to look up in the session data store. Reade http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3472581/PHP-Tutorial-Sessions.htm to explain the relationship between cookies and sessions. PHPSESSID is the name of the cookie (usually)