# PHP: $_SESSION doesn't seem to get set. Any idea?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, authentication

I got through this SO Q/A while searching why my session wouldn't get set.

[`On $_GET set $_SESSION won't work`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453067/on-get-set-session-wont-work)

I don't really get whether this applies to my case. Here it goes.

**index.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["authenticated"])) $_SESSION["authenticated"] = false; 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
...
```

Then, I call the following when the user authenticates himself.

**authenticate.php**

```
<?php
require_once "data/data_access.php";

$userName = "";
$password = "";

if (isset($_REQUEST["userName"])) $userName = $_REQUEST["userName"];
if (isset($_REQUEST["password"])) $password = $_REQUEST["password"];

$isAuthentic = isAuthenticUser($userName, $password);
$_SESSION["authenticated"] = $isAuthentic;
echo $isAuthentic;
?>
```

I also have this authentication-thing checked every 5 seconds in order to create the buttons for the section the user is in.

**authenticated.php**

```
<?php echo isset($_SESSION["authenticated"]) && $_SESSION != false ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>
```

and my Ajax call setup:

**my_project.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() { startAuthenticationChecking(); });

function startAuthenticationChecking() { 
    setInterval(function() { ajaxSession("authenticated.php"); }, 5000);
}

function ajaxSession(actionURL) {
    var authenticated = false;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: actionURL,
        success: function(authenticated) {
            alert(authenticated);
            if (authenticated) {
                if (("#addNewAtvButtonDiv").is(":empty"))
                    $("#addNewAtvButtonDiv").add("<button id='newAtvButton'>Inscrire un nouveau VTT en inventaire</button>");
                if (("#addNewSledButtonDiv").is(":empty"))
                    $("#addNewSledButtonDiv").add("<button id='newSledButton'>Inscrire un nouvel UTT en inventaire</button>");
                if (("#addNewUtvButtonDiv").is(":empty"))
                    $("#addNewUtvButtonDiv").add("<button id='newUtvButton'>Inscrire une nouvelle motoneige</button>");
                $("button").button();
            } else {
                $("#addNewAtvButtonDiv").children().remove();
                $("#addNewSledButtonDiv").children().remove();
                $("#addNewUtvButtonDiv").children().remove();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

> **My Problem**

Though I set `$_SESSION["authenticated"] = false` right after the `session_start();`, when the `ajaxSession()` asks whether a user is authenticated through `authenticated.php`, it always returns `'false'`. Event after an authentication using `authenticate.php` with proper credentials.

*Related question: [`PHP / Ajax : How to show/hide DIV on $_SESSION variable value?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110684/php-ajax-how-to-show-hide-div-on-session-variable-value)*

Any help welcome! I've been working on this for a few nights and days lately, and still am.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running `session_start();` on every single page?

Comment: @Nytangel: Nope, I don't. Only `index.php` can start a session. Then, I mainly use Ajax to change and load sections on the page, all using `$.post()`, `$.ajax()`, `$("#div_id").load()`, etc.

Comment: session_start() is required on all PHP pages. If there's already cookie that tells PHP there's an existing session, it will populate $_SESSION[] properly. If its a clean start, it will do initialization. So, put session_start() on every PHP file you have pls.

Comment: Make sure to turn on **ALL** error reporting to see if you have any errors. Also, are you running all the code on the same domain? (with or without *www*)

Comment: @Ken Cheung: I thought `session_start();` would simply start over a new session, you know, this kind of session which expires after 20 minutes? I'll do as told and keep you informed. Thanks for the cue! =)

Comment: @user0000001: I'm actually developing using `wamp` and `Notepad++`. Wamp listens to `http://localhost:81`, so I suppose it is the same domain, isn't it (really asking the question here)?

Comment: @WillMarcouiller Yes, it is. Have you tried to turn on all error reporting.

Comment: @user0000001: I can find php_log.log under the `wamp/log` directory. I often use `file_put_contents` to create a text file with the information I wanna check, etc. I turned on logs on Wamp. I put some traces using javascript alerts...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that all pages that use `$_SESSION` variables have `session_start();` declared before any output.

It looks like **authenticate.php** doesnt have `session_start();` declared, but uses a session request below.

> $_SESSION["authenticated"] = $isAuthentic;

This will cause problems unless you have included/required the file **authenticate.php**, and the parent file has the `session_start();` declared.

N.B:

session_start(); will either create a session or resume one. It is required on every page that uses session variables.

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

Comment: Unless `data/data_access.php` has it.

Comment: @user0000001 Sure, you might be right. It definetly worth checking all avenues! Thanks!

Comment: Now, when I place an alert on the `ajaxSession()` function, it reports currently that I am authenticated or not. I guess I shall open another question as to how to add and remove controls from the HTML code and connect them with events using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to checking that you have session_start(), I have run into issues with session variables not reporting values correctly if they have not been declared before checking if they are set or checking their value.

So try placing this:

```
$_SESSION["authenticated"];
```

Before your:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["authenticated"])) $_SESSION["authenticated"] = false;
```